# Compare user input against a multidimensional array element in Java using loops

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am still newbie to Java so I am having a problem with my program. I am trying to write a small program showing table booking system, it shows all available tables then takes the user input and compares it against a multidimensional array that holds all the table numbers then assign that value with "[XX]"
so if the user tries to book the same number again they won't be able to.

I can't seem to find a way to compare the user input against the array or to assign the new value "[XX]".

The code is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Random; 







public class exercises {
    
    public static void compare(String tableEnt, String tables [][])
    {
        for(int k=0; k<tables.length; k++)
        {
            if(tableEnt.equals(tables[k]))
                System.out.println("The number has been entered before.");
        }
    }
    
    
    // multidimensional array to display all table numbers. 
    static String tables [][] = {   
            {" [01] " , " [02] " , " [03] " , " [04]  " , " [05] " , " [06] " , " [07]  "},
            {" [08] " , " [09] " , " [10] " , " [11]  " , " [12] " , " [13] " , " [14]  " + " \n "},

            {" [15] " , " [16] " , " [17] " , " [18]  " , " [19] " , " [20] " , " [21]  "},
            {" [22] " , " [23] " , " [24] " , " [25]  " , " [26] " , " [27] " , " [28]  " + " \n "},

            {" [29] " , " [30] " , " [31] " , " [32]  " , " [33] " , " [34] " , " [35]  "},
            {" [36] " , " [37] " , " [38] " , " [39]  " , " [40] " , " [41] " , " [42]  "}};
    
    
    // A method for displaying all tables
            public static void displayTable() {
                    
                    for(int i =0; i<6; i++) {
                        for(int j=0; j<7; j++) {
                            System.out.print(tables[i][j]);
                        }
                        System.out.println();   
                    }
            } 
    
     

        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Variable declarations: 
            
            boolean found = false;
            
            
            
            int min = 1;
            int max = 42;
         
            
            String name;
            int newTable = 1;
            //int tableID;
            
        // boolean answer;
            
            //Welcome message to the customer
            System.out.println("Welcome to the booking system > ");
            System.out.println();
            
            System.out.println("Please enter your full-name> ");
            Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            name = input1.next();
        
            
                while (true) {
                
                displayTable();
                System.out.println();
            
            System.out.println("Thank you, " + name );  
            
            
            
                
            
            
                
            for (int k = 0; k < tables.length; k++) {
                
                System.out.println("Enter a table number");
                int tableID = input2.nextInt();
                String tableString = Integer.toString(tableID);
                
                
                if(tableString.equals(tables[k])) {
                    System.out.println("This table is booked.");
                }
                
                else { System.out.println("Your allocated table is: ");
                  int random_int = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
                  System.out.println(random_int);
                    
                
                
                }
                
            }
            
                
            
            
            
            
                }   
                
                
             
            
        


 

            


 
     
     
      }
         
}
```

Comment: In the compare method you compare a string with a String array and the result is always false.

Comment: Is this a home work ? I will give you some hints, **1)** the table you use is 2d, so you have to use two loops, one inside the other, and check the input with table[..][..], so you can correct your compare method. **2)** you can add anther table, that contain exactly the same  number of elements, where you put in a `bool` value, at first all element are `false` (to say it is not yet reserved), then if one table is reserved you turn it to `true`. in your method compare, you check check at the same position of the table (false or true) to know if it is already reserved or not. good luck.

Comment: @ibra Thank you for the tips! The command program is for an university class. I am still stuck on finding a way to compare the user input against the 2d array elements, I know I need to implement some boolean somewhere but I can't seem to figure it out. My second issue is not knowing how to replace that element which the user entered with another value on the array. Any extra advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 1) the first, is easy,  user_input = read the user input;  after two loops (i and j indices) on the 2d array, and you check if (user_input == array[i][j]), if yes , you check the other 2d array of boolean, if it is already reserved or not, lik if (array_bool[i][j] == true) ; let say that true means it is already reserved, so you say (print) , this already taken, choose another ... 2) if the value in bool array is false, you can tell the user, ok you reservation is OK, and then you change (mark) in the array_bool as true like array_bool[i][j] = true;   you can strie the user choice also.